# Bash: How to declare empty array, and then add variables to it

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I was hoping a kind person more intelligent than me could help me out here.

I am working on a Bash script, and in it there is a `for` loop that will go around an unknown/undefined number of times.

Now, in this `for` loop, there will be a value assigned to a variable. Let's call this variabe: `$var1`

Each time the loop goes (and I will never know how many times it goes), I would like to assign the value inside `$var1` to an array, slowly building up the array as it goes. Let's call the array `$arr`

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in $( seq 0 $unknown ); do
    ...
    some commands that will make $var1 change...
    ...

    arr=("${arr[@]}" "$var1")
done
```

However, when I want to echo or use the values in the array `$arr`, I get no results

Perhaps someone will kindly help me in the right direction?

I would really appreciate it so much.

Comment: `arr+=("$var1")` will populate the array inside the loop, and if you really  want to define an empty array before/outside the loop,  `arr=()`  Or `declare -a arr`

Comment: Show us how you're trying to use the values in the array, and ensure that you're providing not pseudocode but a working example we can run ourselves without needing to make any changes to see your problem (as described in the [mre] definition).

Comment: BTW, in general, `for i in $(seq 0 $unknown)` would be better written as `for ((i=0; i<unknown; i++))`. `seq` is not a standardized command or part of the shell itself, and running an external command when not needed is generally inefficient. (The POSIX-compliant alternative is wordier: `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; do ...; i=$((i + 1)); done` -- there's a reason ksh and bash provide the shorter form).

Comment: Thanks, Charles Duffy. I'm learning as I go...

Comment: I've voted to re-open this - it appears to me that, while the proposed dupe was *related* to arrays, it was a totally *different* question regarding why `echo ${arr}` only ever gave the first element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare and add to a `bash` array as follows:

```
declare -a  arr       # or arr=()
arr+=("item1")
arr+=("item2")
```

Simple as that.

After executing that code, the following assertions (among others) are true:

```
${arr[@]}  == item1 item2
${#arr[@]} == 2
${arr[1]}  == item2
```

---

In terms of the code you provided, you would use:

```
declare -a arr
for i in $( seq 0 $unknown ); do
    ...
    some commands that will make $var1 change...
    ...

    arr+=("$var1")
done
```